# Items with dynamic content in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm pretty new to Android and I have a question about an application that I'm trying to develop. 
My problem is about listview and adapter: I have a list of objects that contain information about a user's favorite routes (i created an object FavouriteRoute and i pass an ArrayList to the BaseAdapter). However, each object can contain a variable number of cities, of stops and days of the week ... how do I handle this dynamic content and show it inside of each row of listview? What's the best approach? I have to manage these elements within the getView () of the adapter and insert them dynamically within the layout of each row?

Comment: Well, you can go make your own CustomListView Adapter (tons of guides online) so that you can display more information about the Object per line item in your list.

Comment: @Razgriz I already have a custom adapter for the list of objects FavouriteRoute, but I don't know how many elements can contain any object. How do I handle a variable number of information for each object within the row to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the reference of these tutorials to learn creating your adapter which will server your purpose.

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

If you want that some of your views are visible and some are not then in getView() do this:

```
if(your condition)
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

after inflating the views.

Comment: probably I am not very good at explaining :) I have a problem similar to the play store. I have a series of rows, but each row can contain a variable number of cards whose information is stored in the object FavouriteRoute.

Comment: In the adapter you can write the logic of which view to hide/show according to some condition.

Comment: But how could I do this? Do you know any tutorials?